# Running Multiple Jobs using Scheduler in Real time application

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

Can anyone help me out to choose which scheduler between "Quartz" or "Quartz+Spring" to run multiple jobs simultaneously in real time application.

Comment: I would suggest Quartz as that's what we have been using for more than 3 years now.

Comment: Are you currently using Spring in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Quartz can run multiple jobs without Spring. Use Spring if you want the features that Spring brings to the table. I would use Spring, because Spring is a great integration framework and makes it easy to integrate technologies like Quartz into an application.

Comment: Thanks robbr. May be second one is better option than first one.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) class.

Refer this tutorial

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/